# What is the right way to use a different base theme for some pages when applying custom theme?

Tags: 8, theming

I know that custom theme usually inherited from the "stable" theme, and the default backend theme is "seven. I like the UI of "/user/login","/user/register" and "/forum" pages. If I use a custom theme inherited from "stable", how can I make the UI apperance of these special pages stay in "seven" theme? I tried to set the "base theme" to "classy" or "false", but the theme suggestions still choose the "stable" as a default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the UI appearance of these special pages stay in
>   "seven" theme?

Seven is the default theme for admin paths in Drupal. To mark special pages like the user login as admin path use the module [Admin Login Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_login_path).

You can add your own paths in a custom route subscriber like the one from the module:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\admin_login_path\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    // Define the routes we want to use the admin theme.
    $login_routes = ['user.login', 'user.register', 'user.pass'];
    foreach ($collection->all() as $name => $route) {
      if (in_array($name, $login_routes)) {
        $route->setOption('_admin_route', TRUE);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your so quick answer. This module works perfect for the path like 'user/login' and 'user/register' of user module. But it seems have no effect on the path of '/forum', is there any solution for that?

Comment: See the second part of the answer. Copy the code to your custom module and modify the path list.

Comment: I did add 'forum' to the $login_routes parameter in modules/admin_login_path/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php, but it has no effect.

Comment: You have to add the route name `forum.index`. Install Devel and go to /devel/routes to see all routes.

Comment: That's really wonderful! Yes, all the path can run under the backend theme now, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: there are modules for D8 that allow you more control over which theme to use on which pages:

- [Switch Page Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/switch_page_theme)
- [Theme Change](https://www.drupal.org/project/theme_change)

In D7 the most popular is [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey).